# fabric.js adding multiple text using button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I want to add multiple text on  my canvas using click of a button but as i click the button again it reload s the canvas and as loaded my first text again here is my code....is there any better way to do it.???

```
function text()
{

var m,n;
m=150;
n=60;
var tex=document.getElementById("tex");
var tex1=document.getElementById("tex1");


var te=tex.value;
var te1=tex1.value;



var canvas=new fabric.Canvas('can');    

var text=new fabric.Text( te ,{

top: m,
left: n

});

canvas.add(text);
}

function text2()
{

var m,n;
m=150;
n=60;

var tex1=document.getElementById("tex1");



var te1=tex1.value;



var canvas=new fabric.Canvas('can');    


var text1=new fabric.Text( te1 ,{

top: m,
left: n

});
canvas.add(text1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

finally i got it i dont know where i was making mistake but finally this code of piece is working for me but still can any body tell me my mistake

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {

     var can=new fabric.Canvas('can');
    $("#d").click(function(e) {


       rect=new fabric.Text('New Text',{
        top:Math.floor(Math.random()*350+1),
        left:Math.floor(Math.random()*250+1),
         fill:'red'


        });
    can.add(rect);
    });
});

</script>
<body>
<canvas id="can" width="700" height="500" style=" border:0.2em solid #000;" > </canvas>




<div class="controls"> 


   <button id="d" onclick="text()">ADD TEXT</button>
</div>
```